# How to refresh table data on all sheets

Tags: excel, vbscript, database-connection, connection-string

I need to run a VBScript that can dynamically set a SQL Server connection string, taking server name and database name from Excel cells, and refresh tables in all worksheets of the file.

I currently have this script against a 'Refresh' button on the 'Setup' sheet (from where it takes the server and database names):

```
Sub Refresh_Click()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim sServer As String
Dim sDatabase As String
Dim sTableName As String
Dim vDestinationRg As Variant
Dim sQuery(1 To 24) As String
Dim vQueryArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim isSplit As Boolean
Dim sUsername As String
Dim sPassword As String

Set Sh = ActiveSheet


j = 1
isSplit = True
vQueryArray = Application.Transpose(Sh.Range("U1:U10"))
For i = LBound(vQueryArray) To UBound(vQueryArray)
    If vQueryArray(i) <> "" Then
        isSplit = False
        sQuery(j) = sQuery(j) & Trim(vQueryArray(i)) & vbCrLf
    ElseIf Not isSplit Then
        isSplit = True
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i


sServer = Sheets("Setup").Range("F5").Value
sDatabase = Sheets("Setup").Range("F7").Value
vDestinationRg = Array("$H$12")
sUsername = "username"
sPassword = "********"

For i = LBound(sQuery) To UBound(sQuery)

    If sQuery(i) = "" Then Exit Sub

    sTableName = "Result_Table_" & Replace(Replace(Sh.Name, " ", ""), "-", "") & "_" & i

    On Error Resume Next
    Sh.ListObjects(sTableName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Sh.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User Id=" & sUsername & "; Password=" & sPassword & ";Data Source=" & sServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & sDatabase & ""), Destination:=Sh.Range(vDestinationRg(i - 1))).QueryTable
        .CommandText = sQuery(i)
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = sTableName
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

I have a select query written in cell "U1" of the 'Setup' sheet and it creates and populates the table into the destination range starting from "H12".

But instead of placing the query on the 'Setup' sheet I want to write queries on different worksheets which would populate tables in the respective worksheets, with only this one Refresh button click on the Setup sheet.

How can I do this?

I have been told it can be achieved without writing VBScript also, but no luck there! I tried adding SQL server connections to the workbook, but can't make it dynamic from there.

Comment: Are you talking about VBScript or VBA?  I'm pretty sure it's the latter. And can't you just use the same script you're using and have your sub-procedure switch sheets instead of pulling all its info from `Setup` sheet?

Comment: You can definitely set up a bunch of tables in a workbook each with it's own query against a SQL Server database. You can refresh them all at once with the Refresh All command in the Data tab. You can have parameters in each worksheet that your queries recognize and you can have the tables recalculate whenever a parameter in a worksheet changes. All without VBA, which is what you mean. You might want to ask a more specific question about how to do those things.